# MongoDB, как сделать insert внутрь объекта в коллекции?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

В коллекции todolists Храню объекты:
{name: "Books", needs: [{task: "HarryPotter#1", isCompleted: false}, {task: "HarryPotter#2", isCompleted: true}]}

использую React, redux, express.
Для того, чтобы по API получить выборку необходимых 'needs' экспортирую модуль:

```
exports.allNeeds = (activeID, cb) => {
db.get().collection('todolists').find({_id: ObjectID(activeID)}, {needs: 1}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    console.log('ABFDS', docs[0].needs);
    if(docs.length != 0) {
            cb(err, docs[0].needs);
    } else {
        cb(err, false);
    }
})
```

}

Но получил потребность записать todo-шку в объект с name-om "Books", 
как мне попасть именно в поле needs, чтобы за-insert-ить туда объект?

```
exports.addTodo = (activeID, todo, cb) => { ... }
```

Или мне нужно только создавать еще одну коллекцию todos, где у каждой тудушки будет храниться id объекта todolist, к которому она привязана?

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить. 
Через метод update просто апдейтим данные:

```
exports.addTodo = (activeID, todo, cb) => {
db.get().collection('todolists').update({_id: ObjectID(activeID)}, { $push: { needs: { task: todo.task, isCompleted: todo.isCompleted } } }, (err, result) => {
            cb(err, result);
})
```

}